# How to word an old boss was unfair?

Tags: job-search, resignation, applications, ex-colleagues

In my application they ask to explain why I left my previous job. I left because the setting wasn't for me in the sense that there were younger associates, which lead to a lot of gossip and my old boss was one of them. I ultimately left because my associates informed me that the manager was telling them he was going to fire me. When addressed with this dilemma he denied but continued to threaten behind my back. I obviously don't want to say all that so, how should I explain all that in a basic synopsis?

Comment: I think hostile work environment is accurate. Otherwise I may suggest you talk about the corporate culture there. Sounds like many of your colleagues behavior probably affected productivity. Cite a few examples while not naming names.

Comment: "it was not a good fit"

Comment: "Not a good fit" or "looking for a more supportive environment"

Answer (score 5):

You say that the corporate culture was not a good fit and then you describe the work conditions that you think would be a good fit for you.

You may need to be prepared to say why you didn't think it was good fit although talking preemptively about what kind of corporate culture you want will likely forestall this.

Don't say anything horribly negative about that particular boss or company at all if you can help it. You could say for instance that you felt that the workplace had a lot of cliques and that you didn't fit into any and it made you feel uncomfortable. But don't say it as: they were a gossipy bunch who told lies about me behind my back.

Think through what to say pretty thoroughly as far as culture, I might not want to hear that you don't like working with younger people if my staff are mostly younger. On the other hand if that is true, Then you don't; want to move to another job where you won't be happy. But I might like to hear that you prefer to work in a cooperative environment rather than a competitive one (unless my workplace is super competitive, in which case you might not be happy there anyway if you prefer cooperation). I have found through the years, it is better to get filtered out for cultural reasons before starting a job than to go to work in a place where there is no chance you will fit in and feel comfortable. Sometimes that means it takes a longer to find the right fit, but that is better than leaving one job you hate for another one you hate more.

Answer (score 0):

The First Rule of job interviews: never say any bad from your previous companies.

What should you say then... well... afaik, I would ask this on the workplace SE.

Don't lie, but re-interpret the actual event on a way which is not harming to your previous work, even in the case if they were really bad.

The reason behind that: if you do, *they may think, that you will say also negative from them in the job interviews in the future.* Furthermore:

- you don't win anything in it
- if you say some negative from them, they will think on that, what could have been *really* behind that (i.e. maybe you were bad and not your employer).

If you don't say any bad, they will think, that maybe you try to defend your ex-employer, because you act on this First Rule (which is well-known for most bosses of the Earth). It is far better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concentrating why you want to leave, focus more on why you want to move on. e.g. you are more interested in the work that you'll be doing for the new job, pick out things about them and the job that you'll like.

Answer (score -2):

Say that he provided a stressful professional environment and don't say anything further.

That's what I said to my next employer back in 1998 when they asked me why I had left - the actual reason why I had left was that the CEO had bugged the company cafeteria and caught me calling him a thief and a liar. Which he was. Too bad he couldn't handle the truth but that was his problem not mine and it wasn't my fault that it sucked to be him.

I had no trouble with my next employer. Best of all, he was a contractor who paid me twice as much. As long as you are sane and sensible and you come across as sane and sensible, you'll be OK.